# Javascript prompt message query

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I tried writing a code for the above image forming a question and list of options with radio button. If user selects the correct answer the message should display as " answer : correct " and " answer : incorrect " for wrong answer i tried until this and if user doesn't select any option and clicks on submit button it should display message as "please select any option". I tried writing code for that like this in html and javascript but i am not getting output. Can anyone help me with this

[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyhyr.jpg)

```js
function answer() {
  var ans = document.getElementById("ans3")
  var status1 = ans.checked
  var btn2 = document.getElementById("button1")

  if (status1 == true) {
    document.getElementById("lab").innerHTML = "answer : correct"
  } else {
    document.getElementById("lab").innerHTML = "answer : incorrect "
  }
}


function disp() {
  var click = document.getElementById("button1").value
  if (click == "") {
    document.getElementById("lab2").innerHTML = "answer: please select any option"
  }
}
disp()
```

```html
<form>
  <center>
    <div style="background-color:slateblue; width:70%; height:530px;">
      <br></br>
      <input placeholder="enter email" type="text" id="finp" onkeyup="dis()"></input>
      <br></br>
      <input placeholder="enter password" disabled type="password" id="sinp" onkeyup="dis1()"></input>
      <br></br>
      <input type="button" value="Login" disabled id="btn"></input>
      <br></br>
      <hr></hr>
      <h2 style="color:white;"> In which tag &ltScript&gt tag should be specified ?</h2>
      <br></br>
      <input type="radio" name="abc" id="ans1"> <strong style="color:white;">&ltHead&gt </strong></input>
      <br></br>
      <input type="radio" name="abc"><strong style="color:white;"> &ltBody&gt </strong></input>
      <br></br>
      <input type="radio" name="abc" id="ans3"> <strong style="color:white;">Both &ltBody&gt and &ltHead&gt </strong></input>
      <br></br>
      <input type="radio" name="abc"><strong style="color:white;"> None of the above</strong> </input>
      <br></br>
      <strong style="color:white;" id="lab">answer : </strong>
      <strong style="color:white;" id="lab2"></strong>
      <br></br>
      <input type="button" value="submit" id="button1" onclick="answer()"></input>
    </div>
  </center>
</form>
```

Comment: you want that message to appear after user clicks on the button right?

Comment: Yes sir. To appear after clicking on submit but without selecting any option

Comment: try the answer belowe. I hope it would help

Answer (score 0):

several little things to change to make running your code :

- first in the disp function you do `var click = document.getElementById("button1").value` you will get the value of the button and not the fact if form have been reply or not -> for this part i can propose you to store form state in a variable (in my sample i just declare status1 as a global variable)
- then i advice you to use innerText when you just change text inside div
- last point in the answer method you modify `lab` div but you stored your reply in `lab2`i just change the selector

```js
var status1;
function answer() {
  var ans = document.getElementById("ans3")
  status1 = ans.checked;
  var btn2 = document.getElementById("button1")

  if (status1 == true) {
    document.getElementById("lab2").innerText = "correct"
  } else {
    document.getElementById("lab2").innerText = "incorrect "
  }
}


function disp() {
  if (!status1) {
    document.getElementById("lab2").innerText = "please select any option"
  }
}
disp()
```

```html
<form>
  <center>
    <div style="background-color:slateblue; width:70%; height:530px;">
      <br></br>
      <input placeholder="enter email" type="text" id="finp" onkeyup="dis()"></input>
      <br></br>
      <input placeholder="enter password" disabled type="password" id="sinp" onkeyup="dis1()"></input>
      <br></br>
      <input type="button" value="Login" disabled id="btn"></input>
      <br></br>
      <hr></hr>
      <h2 style="color:white;"> In which tag &ltScript&gt tag should be specified ?</h2>
      <br></br>
      <input type="radio" name="abc" id="ans1"> <strong style="color:white;">&ltHead&gt </strong></input>
      <br></br>
      <input type="radio" name="abc"><strong style="color:white;"> &ltBody&gt </strong></input>
      <br></br>
      <input type="radio" name="abc" id="ans3"> <strong style="color:white;">Both &ltBody&gt and &ltHead&gt </strong></input>
      <br></br>
      <input type="radio" name="abc"><strong style="color:white;"> None of the above</strong> </input>
      <br></br>
      <strong style="color:white;" id="lab">answer : </strong>
      <strong style="color:white;" id="lab2"></strong>
      <br></br>
      <input type="button" value="submit" id="button1" onclick="answer()"></input>
    </div>
  </center>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Form API to check if there is a selected value for any elements with the name set to `abc`. If it is an empty string, then there is nothing selected.

Also, I do not recommend giving radio buttons IDs, because they are grouped together by name anyways. Instead, give the correct radio button an attribute such as `data-correct`. Then, just map through them and see if the selected one is correct or not based on its presence.

```js
const form = document.forms.question;
var btn2 = document.getElementById('button1');
const lab2 = document.querySelector('#lab');

function answer() {
    const isAnswered = form.elements.abc.value !== '';
    const isCorrect = !![...form.elements.abc].find((radio) => radio.checked && radio.hasAttribute('data-correct'));
    const text = !isAnswered ? 'Please select an answer' : `${isCorrect ? 'Correct' : 'Incorrect'}`;

    lab2.textContent = text
}

function disp() {
    var click = document.getElementById('button1').value;
    if (click == '') {
        document.getElementById('lab2').innerHTML = 'answer: please select any option';
    }
}
disp();
```

```html
<form id="question">
    <div style="background-color:slateblue; width:70%; height:530px;">
    <br></br>
    <input placeholder="enter email" type="text" id="finp" onkeyup="dis()"></input>
    <br></br>
    <input placeholder="enter password" disabled type="password" id="sinp" onkeyup="dis1()"></input>
    <br></br>
    <input type="button" value="Login" disabled id="btn"></input>
    <br></br>
    <hr></hr>
    <h2 style="color:white;"> In which tag &ltScript&gt tag should be specified ?</h2>
    <br></br>
    <input type="radio" name="abc"><strong style="color:white;">&ltHead&gt </strong></input>
    <br></br>
    <input type="radio" name="abc"><strong style="color:white;"> &ltBody&gt </strong></input>
    <br></br>
    <input type="radio" name="abc" data-correct> <strong style="color:white;">Both &ltBody&gt and &ltHead&gt </strong></input>
    <br></br>
    <input type="radio" name="abc"><strong style="color:white;"> None of the above</strong> </input>
    <br></br>
    <strong style="color:white;" id="lab">answer : </strong>
    <strong style="color:white;" id="lab2"></strong>
    <br></br>
    <input type="button" value="submit" id="button1" onclick="answer()"></input>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function answer() {
  if(
     [...document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]')].every(element => !element.checked)
  ) {
     document.getElementById("lab").innerHTML = "answer: please select any option";
     return 
  }
  var ans = document.getElementById("ans3")
  var status1 = ans.checked
  var btn2 = document.getElementById("button1")

  if (status1 == true) {
    document.getElementById("lab").innerHTML = "answer : correct"
  } else {
    document.getElementById("lab").innerHTML = "answer : incorrect "
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <center>
    <div style="background-color:slateblue; width:70%; height:530px;">
      <br></br>
      <input placeholder="enter email" type="text" id="finp" onkeyup="dis()"></input>
      <br></br>
      <input placeholder="enter password" disabled type="password" id="sinp" onkeyup="dis1()"></input>
      <br></br>
      <input type="button" value="Login" disabled id="btn"></input>
      <br></br>
      <hr></hr>
      <h2 style="color:white;"> In which tag &ltScript&gt tag should be specified ?</h2>
      <br></br>
      <input type="radio" name="abc" id="ans1"> <strong style="color:white;">&ltHead&gt </strong></input>
      <br></br>
      <input type="radio" name="abc"><strong style="color:white;"> &ltBody&gt </strong></input>
      <br></br>
      <input type="radio" name="abc" id="ans3"> <strong style="color:white;">Both &ltBody&gt and &ltHead&gt </strong></input>
      <br></br>
      <input type="radio" name="abc"><strong style="color:white;"> None of the above</strong> </input>
      <br></br>
      <strong style="color:white;" id="lab">answer : </strong>
      <strong style="color:white;" id="lab2"></strong>
      <br></br>
      <input type="button" value="submit" id="button1" onclick="answer()"></input>
    </div>
  </center>
</form>
```